# probability theory question from textbook Probability Models by John Haigh

Tags: probability

This is page 7 in Probability Models by John Haigh. I'm confused about this corollary 1.3.

Could someone explain what i and j mean at the right side of $S_2$. Is $j$ equal to $i+1$?

See the original text in the [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6ILc8.png).

[image: the bang makes it show on screen]

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$S_2=\sum\limits_{i<j}\mathsf P(A_i\cap A_j)$ is the sum of all $\mathsf P(A_i\cap A_j)$ over each pair of indices $i, j$ where $i<j$.

Also written $S_2=\sum\limits_{i=1}^{n-1}\sum\limits_{j=i+1}^n\mathsf P(A_i\cap A_j)$

That is the sum of the probability of the intercepts of all pairs of events from the sequence $[A_1,A_2,\ldots, A_n]$.

$$S_2=\mathsf P(A_1\cap A_2)+\mathsf P(A_1\cap A_2)+\cdots+\mathsf P(A_1\cap A_n)+\mathsf P(A_2\cap A_3)+\cdots\cdots+\mathsf P(A_{n-1}\cap A_n)$$

---

Similarly ${S_3=\sum\limits_{i<j<k}\mathsf P(A_i\cap A_j\cap A_k)}$ as the summation of the probability for the intercepts of each triple from the sequence.

And so forth, to $S_n=\mathsf P(A_1\cap A_2\cap\cdots\cap A_n)$ ; since there is only one such $n$-tuple that can be formed from the sequence of $n$ events.

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1):

$\sum_{i<j}$ denotes sum over both $i$ and $j$ with the restriction $i<j$.